# Drag and Drop Slider updating count too fast

Tags: reactjs

To update a slide count I'm using drag and drop interaction using https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd. I'm using as a reference, the movement of the slide calling a method after reaching a certain distance. The issue is that the count keeps growing very fast as the event is being called a lot of times after reaching that distance.

Full demo on https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-drop-react-rnd-cm8x3

I have tried disabling the drag and drop but the counter increases so fast that there is no time to stop it. I have also tried setting up the position to the beginning but it seems it only updates when the user releases the click (or the finger). I have also tried setting up a small distance but doesn't work because if you go to fast it doesn't compute or if you go to slow the count keeps increasing fast.

```
type DraggableData = {
  node: HTMLElement,
  x: number,
  y: number,
  deltaX: number, deltaY: number,
  lastX: number, lastY: number
};


dragin = (_e: MouseEvent, data: DraggableData ) => {
    // @TODO: It should return to the starting position with the previous step
    if (400 < data.x && data.x < 410) {
        this.prevStep();
    }

    console.log(data.x);
    // @TODO: It should return to the starting position with the next step
    if (745 < data.x) {
        // Needs to return to beginning!!!!
        this.setState({
            xPosition: 0,
            yPosition: 0
        });
        // The code keeps executing a lot of times.
        // Maybe create a variable that stores only the first time it hits
        // or how can it be controlled?
        console.log('next Step');
        this.nextStep();
    }
};
```

A demo of the code can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-drop-react-rnd-cm8x3

When moving to the right, the slide should disappear, then the next slide appears in the initial position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a workaround solution. It's not a good idea to use an item as state and update it because, as commented previously, when reaching the condition it updates and updates until the drag has stopped. To avoid it is better to use as state an array of items, once the condition is reached, delete the item from the array using pop or shift.

```
// Solution
nextStep = () => {
  const { items } = this.state;

  if (items.length === 1) {
    this.setState({ isActive: false });
    return;
  }

  const newItems = [...items];
  newItems.pop();
  this.setState(prevState => ({ items: newItems, step: prevState.step + 1 }));
};

// Old code with issues
nextStep = () => {
  const { step } = this.state;
  if (step === Items.length - 1) {
    this.setState({ isActive: false, step: 0, item: Items[0] });
    return;
  }

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    step: prevState.step + 1,
    item: Items[prevState.step + 1]
  }));
};
```

The updated solution that works can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/drag-drop-react-draggable-6qi1j